# Where is ghci.conf if installing GHC using brew cask in mac?

Tags: macos, haskell, haskell-platform, homebrew-cask

I used homebrew-cask to install haskell-platform in my mac (OS X 10.11.2) by running:

```
brew cask install haskell-platform
```

and it is working well until the day I want to enable syntax highlight in GHCi. I found in [this post](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHCi_in_colour) that I should add one line in `ghci.conf`. But I could not found where this file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a new file in your user directory; the final path should be `~/.ghci` or `/Users/<username>/.ghci`. The file does not exist by default. See [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html) for the full details.